# Cant get out from command window when accidentaly pressed Ctrl alt F1

Tags: command-line, unity, 22.04, tty, interface

When I pressed that command, I couldnt get out, I tried rebooting from command line, restarting the service gmd3 which is the graphics service, I tried ctrl alt f7-f12 and nothing happened, even with alt+arrow key to switch the tty, it only goes until tty6 and starts again in tty1, and finally I tried with the command startx and a White window appeared, it was similar to the blue window on Windows, it said something went wrong and try log out and do it again. Thats what worries me the most.

I actually dont know what to do next, I tried everything. Please if some expert can help me.